# how to copy the value of cursor variable to temp variable in Procedure?

Tags: mysql

```sql
BEGIN
DECLARE cur_var1 CURSOR FOR
        SELECT sum_field1  FROM table1 where field1 = sum_val1  ;

DECLARE cur_var2 CURSOR FOR
        SELECT sum_field2   FROM table2 where field2 = sum_val2  ;

END
```

I want to hold the value of `cur_var1` to a temporary variable say `cur_temp`. Now please let me know is it possible? If possible then how should I write the code.

Comment: This doesn't look like PHP to me. I have tagged it as SQL. Please tag it with the specific SQL version you're talking about (MySQL, Postgres or whatever else).